# How to fastly traverse a directory and count the number of files

Tags: linux

I use Python's `os.walk` function to walk through the directory to count the total number of files under that directory.

However, it runs with approximately about 5 seconds to get the final result and one the cpu core is used about 100%. This is somewhat unacceptable.

So,is there some other method to do this job with less time and less cpu usage.

Comment: `find /path/to/directory -type f | wc -l`?

Comment: How many files do you have? What filesystem and what kind of disk devices? Depending on those, 5 seconds may be quite reasonable.

Comment: @rodrigo , about 18w files under the directory. The file system is ext4. I have not considered that the type of file system may affect the traverse performance.

Comment: @myaut , it finished in about 1.3 seconds and the cpu usage is low too. How does `find` achive that?

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously many alternatives. To keep it simple, what about `ls | wc -l` ?